# Why can some text not be sent via the form?

Tags: php, html, microsoft-edge

Sending the following form ends with a single character `#` shown in the MS Edge browser(`Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134`) and we can expect the final result should be `OK!`. The expected result is shown in other popular browsers. Wrapping the form with the correct HTML5 skeleton with Doctype etc. does not help. Why can some particular text not be sent via the form? Well, to be strict it can as long as I do not touch `$_POST` or I do not want to include this meta tag on my webpage where the form is sent. I can access the post data via `php://input` and everything is there in a raw but this is not a solution.
The issue was found in my own content management framework where some tags(including meta tags) are sent via the form to the PHP script.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    echo "OK!";
} else{
    echo '
        <form action="/" name="template" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <textarea name="test"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></textarea>
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    ';
}
?>
```

Naturally, the source code is saved with UTF-8 as well. Please, drag me away from this path in case I am doing something prohibited or potentially wrong. Eventually, I want to send the complete HTML head section via POST method.

Here are my questions:

1. Why text including `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` cannot be properly sent using post method? Here, there is no question about the processing of the data via PHP script.
2. Is there any reason to search for the issue not in the source code but in web server installation? But, if yes why then it works with other browsers?
3. Can the HTTP requests be for some reason significantly different what might cause the described issue?
4. From where comes `#` can it be from the web server or the edge browser?

I am using `XAMPP 7.2.4` on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't believe meta tags are to be used within form tag.. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Let say, I am sending an article describing the meta tags to local wikipage or want to exchange **locally** the website template with coworkers. In this case, this `meta` tag should be not interpreted.

Comment: "in the MS Edge browser" — Is this the only browser you tested?

Comment: No, my list of check browser is the following: Chrome, Safari, IE, **Edge**, Firefox, and other Firefox'es from Linux distributions but only with the Edge, I had saved some cookie session which I was at least not expecting to cause troubles. I will share info here, in case, I will be able to reproduce the same issue with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not everything should be allowed to send with the form by a user, but any tag is not a reason to be refused by a browser or httpd server.
2. The web server could reject some request, especially along the loaded mod_rewrite module with not a proper configuration,

   4. ...but what is the point of writing the `#` instead of an error message.
3. The main fear is that the HTTP requests might be different, maybe some mechanism against XSS incidentally will catch something? But as the life shown the issue here was somehow connected to cache, default content language and saved cookies.

The original issue from the question is related only to XAMPP <=> MS Edge and it has nothing to do with PHP scripts or UTF-8 encoding. It is established in the community that the meta tag with charset should be used as a safety mechanism, but what is not to be expected is that this meta tag might potentially have the influence on showing the website's content or just `#`. It should be strongly stressed that a similar issue is **not** appearing with other tags. The simplest case in which the scenario could be repeated is with the GET method by sending form data even to the HTML file.

```
http://127.0.0.1/?data=%3Cmeta+http-equiv%3D%22%22+%2F%3E
```

The other decent installations of Apache server have no such issues(I have tried apachelounge on Windows and Apache installations on different linux distributions). Therefore, I claim that reproducing the issue might be difficult and potentially can be the installation specific.

**The** simplest **solution is to use a different version** of XAMPP or other implementation **of the httpd server**.

For those, curious as I am, still, it is not explained why the XAMPP server has the issue with requests only from MS Edge. The typical HTTP request

```
GET /?data=%3Cmeta+http-equiv%3D%22%22+%2F%3E HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

seems not to has any unconventional stuff. There is an obvious `User-Agent` difference with MS Edge

```
GET /?data=%3Cmeta+http-equiv%3D%22%22+%2F%3E HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134
Accept-Language: pl-PL
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=*********
```

and the **Cookie**, and the **Accept-Language**: pl-PL only. To my surprise, it turned out that **cleaning of the browser data** solved my issue.